# Smoothly varying finite dimensional vector subspaces tracing out infinite dimensional locus

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Is it possible that a smoothly varying finite dimensional vector subspaces tracing out infinite dimensional locus?

More precisely, Let $E$ be a vertor bundle on a (compact) smooth manifold $M$ and $T_t:\Gamma(M,E)\to \Gamma(M,E)$ is a smooth family of linear operators, where $\Gamma(M,E)$ is the space of sections. $T_t$ is **smooth** on $t\in \mathbb{R}$ means that if $\{\sigma_i\}$ is a local frame then the coefficients of each $T_t\sigma_i$ with respect to the frame $\{\sigma_i\}$ is smooth in $t$.

Now if $V\subset \Gamma(M,E)$ is a linear subspace of finite dimension.
Is it possible that
$$
\dim span_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\bigcup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\{T_t(V)\}\right)=\infty~?
$$
Is it possible that for any sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\dim~ span_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\bigcup_{|t|<\varepsilon}\{T_t(V)\}\right)=\infty~?
$$

A typical example of this question is when $T_t=e^{-f(t)}de^{f(t)}$ ($f(t)$ is a smooth function on $M$ which depends smoothly on $t$), $E=\bigwedge^\bullet T_M^*$ is the exterior bundle and $V=\mathcal{H}^\bullet(M)$ is the space of harmonic forms.

**Added**:If the above possiblities are possible, I want to know whether $\dim\ker(T_t\mid_V)$ is upper semicontinuous on $t$ for small $t$? That is,
$$
\dim\ker(T_0\mid_V)\geq \dim\ker(T_t\mid_V),\quad |t|<\varepsilon~.
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "smoothly"?  Is $V$ supposed to have some addiitional structure?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, I see your point! What I am looking for is the situation where $span\{v_1(t),\cdots,v_k(t)\}$ is the image of a smooth family of linear operators.

Comment: That doesn't help: what does "smooth" mean?

Comment: The usual notion of "smooth" involves differentiation, which involves limits, and so doesn't make sense in an arbitrary vector space.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, You are right. I will edit my question. I am intrested in the case of smooth family of operators acting on sections of vector bundle over smooth manifolds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely possible. Consider the trivial bundle $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and the operator defined by $T_tf(x)=\cos(tx)f(x)$. Let $V$ be the subspace of constant functions. Since $\{\cos(tx):t\in[0,\infty)\}$ is linearly independent, the union $\bigcup_{t\in I}T_t(V)$ is infinite dimensional for any open $I\subset\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Is it true that $\dim\ker(T_0\mid_V)\geq \dim\ker(T_t\mid_V),~ |t|<\varepsilon~$?

Comment: Not in general. You could, for instance, have $T_t=0$.

Comment: But this does not violate the inequality: $ \dim\ker(T_0\mid_V)= \dim\ker(T_t\mid_V)=\dim V$.

Comment: More specifically, you could have $T_0|_V\neq 0$ and $T_t=0$ and smoothly interpolate between them.